How to use Sqlite in .NET Framework 4.8 unit test project?
I want to use an in-memory Sqlite database in my unit test project. My database is a dbml and I already parse it to a SQL script and create a Sqlite database from it. My database file was created successfully, when I debug my test but as soon as I want to add a seed data in one of my table I got this error:

No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file.

I have configured my data context according to this link and removed all providers from the app.config file:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1158937/SQLite-with-Csharp-Net-and-Entity-Framework
Here is my test:
[TestMethod]
public void Check_Eum_Count()
{
    var db = InMemoryDb.CreateDb();
    db.SeedData();

    var result = db.EumAccessTypes.ToList();

    Assert.IsTrue(result.Count > 0);
}

This is my InMemoryDb:
public class InMemoryDb : DbContext
{
    public InMemoryDb(string dbFilePath) : base("Data Source=" + dbFilePath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(dbFilePath))
        {
            var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbFilePath);
            connection.Open();
            new SQLiteHelper(connection).ParseDbFromDbml();
        }            
    }    
        
    public static InMemoryDb CreateDb()
    {
        return new InMemoryDb("D:\\Databases\\MCS-Test.db");
    }   

    public void SeedData()
    {            
        this.EumAccessTypes.Add(new Dto.EumAccessType { ID= 1, Title= "test"});
        this.SaveChanges();
    }

    public DbSet<Dto.MineInfo> MineInfos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Dto.EumAccessType> EumAccessTypes { get; set; }
}

And this is my data context config and my app.config:
public class SQLiteConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
        public SQLiteConfiguration()
        {
            SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite", SQLiteFactory.Instance);
            SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance);
            SetProviderServices("System.Data.SQLite", (DbProviderServices)SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance.GetService(typeof(DbProviderServices)));
        }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
  </startup>
</configuration>

